# What to do when a package conflicts with a development version of another one?

Tags: packages, incompatibility

I'm not sure about making this question here but I don't know where to do it.

I'm using cvs version of TikZ and from time to time I found it incompatible with some other packages based on its released version. Some time ago it happened with [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) (although I think it's solved) and today happened with [`tikzposter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter) and [tikz-mimo-shapes](https://code.google.com/p/tikz-mimo-shapes/). If I use pgf-2.1 everything works, but with cvs version some error stops compilation.

So, what to do know? With `forest` I sent a message to the author and he provided me a patch which I think was later incorporated into a newer version.

Another option would be to fill a bug report in pgf's place explaining these problems.

An the last one would be to use or not cvs version depending on what package I'm using, but this one is not very comfortable.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 6):

It would be good to inform the developer or maintainer of both packages.

If you would be able to find the cause,

- If the conflict is caused because package X uses internal macros of package Y instead of the official and documented interface, inform the maintainer of X.
- If the conflict occurs while package X uses the official and documented interface of package Y, inform the maintainer of Y, since backward compatibility is lost.

If in doubt, write to both.