# How do I identify the correct maintainer to contact if I find a bug?

Tags: luatex, math-fonts, bugtracking

I believe I found a bug that has hit texlive-base (2022.20221123-1) in Debian Sid yesterday according to [Changelog](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/t/texlive-base/texlive-base_2022.20221123-1_changelog). Consider this minimal example:

```
$ cat test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathfont}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
$ lualatex test.tex
...
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01>
 L3 programming layer <2022-11-02>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathfont/mathfont.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
! Argument of \M@p@tch@decl@re has an extra }.
...
```

Neither `mathfont` nor its only dependency `atveryend` have been updated recently as far as I can tell.

I'd like to file a bug report, but I don't know where. Who should I contact in this case, and how do I find the correct person in general?

Comment: `texdoc mathfont`. There's an email there

Comment: Might be duplicate →[incompatibility - What to do when a package conflicts with a development version of another one? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/what-to-do-when-a-package-conflicts-with-a-development-version-of-another-one)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if the problem lies with `mathfont` in the first place, because it has been working fine last week and hasn't change since then. Anyway, I wrote an e-mail to the address in the docs, maybe he'll know where the problem actually is.

Comment: it is clearly in mathfont. It tries to patch a core LaTeX command, `\DeclareSymbolFont`, and that was changed in the latest release and so now the patch fails. That is a problem with such packages: they often rely on internals which can change.

Comment: To be fair, most of the time there's no way to implement such things at all without relying on internals.

Comment: If a change to the latex format affects a package it is also reasonable to log this as an issue at the latex2e github. It might be an unintentional change we can adjust or it might be we classify it as something for the package maintainer, but either way it is reasonable to report it, especially if a package maintainer is hard to reach.